# How to input any type of data type in scanf?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a basic problem. I am writing a program where I need to enter data in queue. But the data can be of any type. So how can I use `scanf()` function if I am not sure about the data specifier. I guess I can make use of unions but how do I proceed?

Sample:

```
union abc {
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
};


int main()
{
    union abc data;

    printf("enter data");
    scanf("<----------doubt here
```

I am not sure how to use `scanf` when we are not sure about the data type that the user can enter.

Comment: You could read it as a string and find it out yourself based on the function calls available

Comment: if you are not sure about the datatype ,then first take the data using fgets(), then find the type of the input data

Comment: i''ll try it in code, what if the data type entered is user defined how to check then?

Comment: @user2543773, obviously `scanf` can't read a type which it doesn't know of. Once you have a string for a line you can use functions from the C library to do the parsing: `strspn`, `strchr`, `strtok` ...

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot achieve this with `scanf()`.  `scanf()` needs the format specifier for a particular type of data. If you're not sure about the input data type, first use `fgets()` to take the data from user and then perform the data validation / type check inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is

```
union abc a;
scanf("%i", &a.i);
//Since, it is union, you can scan any desired field.
```

But as such, you cannot scanf union with any input entered. If you expect different inputs, then it is better to read the string using `fgets` and parse the string to check if integer or floating point number or character is entered and assign the appropriate value.

Like:

```
char input[250];
abc a;
fgets(input, 250, stdin);
//parse the string.
if(isint(input)) {
   a.i = atoi(input, NULL, 10);
} //similarly for other methods.
```

Comment: Thx,what if the data type is user defined how to check then?

Comment: Again, parse the string and try to fill the user defined structure or union or see if it can be converted to that one. Or it may possible that string has some fixed syntax for a data type. You can check for the syntax and populate the object.